# Getting raw value of a cell of a selected row in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

With

```
console.log(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection());
```

I cann see that I have selected a row and there it is all the values of the row under the `raw` however I was unable to read it.

I have tried

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().raw
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().raw.EMAIL
```

etc, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection `getSelection()` returns array of `Ext.data.Model`.

So what you need to do is

```
var sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
    model = sel[0],
    val = model.get('EMAIL');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

is

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections()
```

So it could be

```
var sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
```

or

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections()[0].get('field');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    ....
    listeners: {
        select: function(selModel, record, index, options){
            alert(record.get('EMAIL'));
                }
        }
```