# Getting a value from a parent grid, use it as title in the child grid ext.js 4

Tags: extjs, grid, selection, extjs4.1, title

The operation I want to do is not easy.I have a first grid (or table) and a secondo one, generated clicking on a cell which is present in every row of the first table. It takes the parameters of the first table and shows some other content of the json which generates the tables.

The second table is included in a column of the first table, it is made by an ajax call and:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window' etc. etc.
```

The ***Problem*** is that i want to take the name of the row of the first table an use it as the name of the second table, which is inside the first. I've found some useful advices ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186682/getting-raw-value-of-a-cell-of-a-selected-row-in-a-grid), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447401/how-to-read-and-set-a-value-of-a-specific-cell-in-an-extjs-grid)) but the work for the "current" table, not for my specific case. Anyone can help?

The code i use is below, but it's very long to read, so i doubt it can be useful.

```
// create the Grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
    store: store1,
    stateful: true,
    collapsible: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'id',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            text     : 'buyer_member_id',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'buyer_member_id'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Client Name',
            width    : 200,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            xtype : 'actioncolumn',
            width : '5%',
            sortable : false,
            items : [{
                icon : '../static/accept.gif',
                tooltip : 'See Admants',
                handler : function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){
                    var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                     var buyer_member_id = row.data.buyer_member_id;
                    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                    };
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method : "GET",     
                        url: '/admants/?buyer_member_id='+ buyer_member_id,
                        success : function(response) {
                            var obj = response;
                            try {
                                obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            } catch (error) {alert("Errore nella decodifica del file json");}
                            if (obj) { 
                                Ext.define('Admants', {
                                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                                fields: [
                                      {name: 'id',    type: 'int', convert: null,    defaultValue:undefined},
                                      {name: 'name',  type: 'string', convert:null,  defaultValue:undefined},
                                      {name: 'group', type: 'string', convert:null,  defaultValue:undefined}
                                ],
                                idProperty: 'id'
                                });
                                var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
                                        groupHeaderTpl: 'Group: {name} ({rows.length} Item{[values.rows.length > 1 ? "s" : ""]})'
                                });
                                var Admantstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                        autoLoad: true,
                                        storeId: 'Admants',
                                        sorters: ['id', 'name','group'],
                                        groupField: 'group',
                                        fields: ['id','name','group'],
                                        data : obj,
                                        model: 'Admants',
                                        proxy: {
                                            type: 'memory',
                                            reader: {
                                                type: 'json',
                                                root: 'admants'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                                title: 'Admants', //this line has to be changed
                                height: 200,
                                width: 400,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                items: {  
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                border: false,
                                store: Admantstore,
                                features: [groupingFeature],
                                columns: [
                                        {
                                            text     : 'id',
                                            flex     : 1,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'id'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text     : 'name',
                                            width    : 300,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'name'
                                        }],
                                }}).show();
                            } else {
                            alert("Invalid response");
                            }
                        },
                        failure : function(response) {
                            alert("Data request failed");
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }]
        }
    ],
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Member Data Sharing',
    renderTo: 'grid-example1',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        enableTextSelection: true
    }
});
```

});

Comment: tryied:`title: function(){       var sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
          model = sel[0],
          val = model.get('name');
          return val
         },` NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

Ok then i used a line that was using the data of the store of the first (parent) table and was assigned to a variable that could be used in all the function. These are the two lines wich do the trick:

```
var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
var buyer_member_id = row.data.buyer_member_id;
var AdmantClient = row.data.name
```

Then i used the AdmantClient variable as a title for the second (child) table/grid.
Hope this helps out.